# How can I omit groups of records where the attribute is based on a 'like' clause across 2 different fields

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need a query to omit groups where the number 16 is present in both records and are present across different attributes within the group . Basically, if we have a 16 somewhere in attributes on different records, then we know what accounts for these groups, and no further analysis is needed on them.  We would like to keep results where 16 only occurs in one record in either attribute, 16 occurs in neither, and records that have nulls in them but do not have the 16 in 2 records in different attributes.

Here is an example:

```
---------------------------------------------
| groupid    | category     |  test_results |
---------------------------------------------
| 001        |  red13tall   |               |
| 001        |              |  blue16small  |
| 002        |  green16small|               |
| 002        |              |  blue16small  |
| 003        |  yellow3tall |               |   
| 003        |              |  green2giant  |
| 004        | orange16tall |               |
| 004        |              |  blue16tall   |
| 005        | red16short   |               |
| 005        | green12bald  |  orange14tall |
| 006        | blue3short   |  red16big     |
| 006        | green16flat  |               |
---------------------------------------------
```

This is the result we are looking for:

```
---------------------------------------------
| groupid    | category     |  test_results |
---------------------------------------------
| 001        |  red13tall   |               |
| 001        |              |  blue16small  |
| 003        |  yellow3tall |               |   
| 003        |              |  green2giant  |
| 005        | red16short   |               |
| 005        | green12bald  |  orange14tall |
 ------------------------------------------
```

Comment: is that your real table structure or is it the result of a query?

Comment: So, each `groupid` will have exactly two rows? And - if I understand correctly - for a group to be excluded, two separate conditions must be true: (1) both rows have a 16 in at least one column; (2) both columns have 16 in at least one of the two rows in the group? That is, if for `groupid= 10` you had `(red13tall, blue12small)` and `(red16tall, blue16giant)`, should this be excluded or not? It doesn't satisfy (1); it is not true that it has a 16 "in both records" - there is no 16 in the first record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table is called `your_table` and has a primary key of `id`, then

```
SELECT t3.groupid, t3.category, t3.test_results
FROM your_table t3
WHERE t3.groupid NOT IN (
  SELECT t1.groupid
  FROM your_table t1, your_table t2
  WHERE t1.id <> t2.id
  AND t1.groupid = t2.groupid
  AND t1.category LIKE '%16%'
  AND t2.test_results LIKE '%16%'
)
```

Note, this assumes you're looking for `16` to appear in two different rows in the 2 different columns. If you don't care if they appear in the same row then you can remove the `t1.id <> t2.id` condition.

Answer (score 1):

One way or another you need conditional counting. If you use analytic functions you can avoid joins, which are often a performance drag.

For the solution below I interpreted your words literally: each group has exactly two rows, and a group is excluded if all three conditions are met: BOTH rows have 16 at least once (in `category` or in `test_results`); 16 appears in `category` at least once; and 16 appears in `test_results` at least once.

You can modify the query very easily if you don't need the condition on each row of the group having 16 at least once (remove all references to `r_ct`).

```
with
     test_data ( groupid, category, test_results ) as (
       select '001', 'red13tall'   , null           from dual union all
       select '001', null          , 'blue16small'  from dual union all
       select '002', 'green16small', null           from dual union all
       select '002', null          , 'blue16small'  from dual union all
       select '003', 'yellow3tall' , null           from dual union all
       select '003', null          , 'green2giant'  from dual union all
       select '004', 'orange16tall', null           from dual union all
       select '004', null          , 'blue16tall'   from dual union all
       select '005', 'red16short'  , null           from dual union all
       select '005', 'green12bald' , 'orange14tall' from dual union all
       select '006', 'blue3short'  , 'red16big'     from dual union all
       select '006', 'green16flat' , null           from dual
     )
--  end of test data (not part of solution); SQL query begins below this line
select   groupid, category, test_results
from     (
           select groupid, category, test_results,
                  count(case when category     like '%16%' then 1 
                             when test_results like '%16%' then 1 end) 
                             over (partition by groupid)               as r_ct,
                  count(case when category     like '%16%' then 1 end) 
                             over (partition by groupid)               as c_ct,
                  count(case when test_results like '%16%' then 1 end) 
                             over (partition by groupid)               as t_ct
           from   test_data
         )
where    r_ct < 2 or c_ct = 0 or t_ct = 0
order by groupid   --  if needed
;
```

**Output**:

```
GROUPID CATEGORY     TEST_RESULTS
------- ------------ ------------
001     red13tall
001                  blue16small
003     yellow3tall
003                  green2giant
005     red16short
005     green12bald  orange14tall

6 rows selected.
```